# Batchscript can't remove line from text file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I've been making a small script that records phone numbers and it works fine but I have problem with getting the removal function to work,and I get the errors: FINDSTR: Cannot open del and FINDSTR: Cannot open /s.

```
@echo off
:menu
cls
echo ^<^<^<^<^< Test Nisse's phone records ^>^>^>^>^>
echo ^<1^>. Search for phone number
echo ^<2^>. Enter a new phone number
echo ^<3^>. Remove phone number
echo ^<4^>. Print all of the telephone record on the screen
echo ^<x^>. Exit 
set /p val="Enter your selection <1-4, x>: " 
if %val%== 1 goto one
if %val%== 2 goto two
if %val%== 3 goto three
if %val%== 4 goto four
if %val%== x goto x

:one
cls
set /p n1="Number: "
findstr /r /c:%n1% telephoneregister.txt
echo.
echo ====================
SET /p =ENTER to go back to menu.
goto menu

:two
cls
set /p p1="Number: " 
echo %p1% >> telephoneregister.txt
echo. 
echo ====================
set /p =ENTER to go back to menu.
goto menu

:three
cls
echo Which number would you like to delete?
set /p num="Telephoneregister: " 
type telephoneregister.txt | findstr /v %num% > telephoneregister1.txt del /s telephoneregister.txt 
type telephoneregister1.txt > tele.txt del /s tele1.txt 
set /p =ENTER to go back to menu.
goto menu

:four
cls
type telephoneregister.txt
echo.
echo ====================
set /p =ENTER to go back to menu.
goto menu

:x
exit
```

Comment: This is one of those types of posts that I am reminded of the "Band Aid" scripts..  One of those "go back to ones."  I love your question and I am reminded of the one post/script that is not really on any script site, but really in a NewsGroup and is - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/sj8IUhMOq6o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require `&` between commands on a single line, otherwise `cmd` will assume the second command is extra arguments to the first.

```
type telephoneregister.txt | findstr /v %num% > telephoneregister1.txt del /s telephoneregister.txt
```

should become

```
type telephoneregister.txt | findstr /v %num% > telephoneregister1.txt&del /s telephoneregister.txt
```

or even easier

```
type telephoneregister.txt | findstr /v %num% > telephoneregister1.txt
del /s telephoneregister.txt
```

or, easier still

```
type telephoneregister.txt | findstr /v %num% > telephoneregister1.txt
move /y telephoneregister1.txt telephoneregister.txt >nul
```

where the `move` command will overwrite the target file with the source. The `/y` means "don't prompt for authority to overrite" and the `1 file(s) moved` message is suppressed by being redirected to `nul`

Comment: This one worked the best for me, thank you so much and thanks everybody else for the help.

Answer (score 2):

In :two, you're writing a space after each phone number:

```
echo %p1% >> telephoneregister.txt
```

Change that to:

```
echo %p1%>> telephoneregister.txt
```

Change :three to:

```
:three
cls
echo Which number would you like to delete?
set /p num="Telephoneregister: " 
type telephoneregister1.txt | findstr /v %num% telephoneregister.txt > telephoneregister1.txt 
copy /y telephoneregister1.txt telephoneregister.txt > nul
del telephoneregister1.txt 
set /p =ENTER to go back to menu.
goto menu
```

The "findstr /v" part will write all lines that don't match the number to your backup file (telephoneregister1.txt).  Then we copy that file back to telephoneregister.txt (overwriting it) and delete the backup file.

Comment: Redirecting numbers without space can be problematic, `echo +43 13 45 12 1>> telephone.txt` will drop the last `1` as it's used as stream number. It's better to place the redirect to the front then `>> telephone.txt echo %p1%`

Comment: @jeb: I tested adding a number that ends in 1 with the script and it doesn't drop.

Comment: It only occurs when there is also a space or a different delimiter before the `1`

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your code in order to address a couple minor details, or to made it simpler. Here it is:

```
@echo off
:menu
cls
echo ^<^<^<^<^< Test Nisse's phone records ^>^>^>^>^>
echo ^<1^>. Search for phone number
echo ^<2^>. Enter a new phone number
echo ^<3^>. Remove phone number
echo ^<4^>. Print all of the telephone record on the screen
echo ^<x^>. Exit 
choice /C 1234x /M "Enter your selection: " 
if %errorlevel% equ 5 exit /B
cls
call :option-%errorlevel%
echo.
echo ====================
SET /p =ENTER to go back to menu.
goto menu


:option-1 Search
set /p n1="Number: "
findstr /i /r /c:%n1% telephoneregister.txt
exit /B

:option-2 Enter
set /p p1="Number: " 
set /P "=%p1%" < NUL >> telephoneregister.txt
echo.>> telephoneregister.txt
exit /B

:option-3 Remove
echo Which number would you like to delete?
set /p num="Telephoneregister: " 
findstr /v %num% telephoneregister.txt > telephoneregister1.txt
move /Y telephoneregister1.txt telephoneregister.txt 
exit /B

:option-4 Print
more telephoneregister.txt
exit /B
```

BTW, you may also manage names after telephone numbers with the exact same code; just "Enter number followed by name" and "Enter number or name to search".